# Run function after geolocation permission accepted

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, geolocation

I'm stumbling on a problem with Geolocation where I need to run a function after the `geolocation` prompt appears on iOS for a user and they click "Accept".

Currently what I'm doing is on `ngOnInit` I check for the users location, but if they haven't accepted yet, the function that I run after checking the users location doesn't work.

This is what I currently have:

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 3000, maximumAge: 100000})
.then((resp) => {
   this.userLocation.lat = resp.coords.latitude;
   this.userLocation.lng = resp.coords.longitude;
   this.getLocation();
}).catch((error) => {
   console.log(error)    
});
```

So the `this.getLocation();` function runs after geolocation finds the location, but how would I run this code after the user accepts the "allow this application to use your location" prompt?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cordova-plugin-geolocation` doesn't really allow that.

You can use another plugins like [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) that allows you to request any permission.

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestLocationAuthorization(function(status){
    switch(status){
        case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.NOT_REQUESTED:
            console.log("Permission not requested");
            break;
        case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.DENIED:
            console.log("Permission denied");
            break;
        case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED:
            console.log("Permission granted always");
            break;
        case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED_WHEN_IN_USE:
            console.log("Permission granted only when in use");
            break;
    }
}, function(error){
    console.error(error);
}, cordova.plugins.diagnostic.locationAuthorizationMode.ALWAYS);
```

[Docs](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/blob/master/README.md#requestlocationauthorization)